# Is there any Akka-based reactive IP-PBX implementation out there?

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, pbx

With the growth of popularity of IP telephony in enterprise environments and in general, is there any implementation of a IP-PBX being transparently scalable, reactive, easily-configurable, suited to high-load requirements out there (preferably based on  Akka+Scala)? Maybe something similar to [3CX Phone System](http://www.3cx.com/phone-system/) and/or [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/).

Also, is this a good use-case for [reactive streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/)?

Thanks.